# asp.net regular expression validator for decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using the below expression to validate a textbox with decimal number. But it accept 12, -1.0,12.0,12.5,1.0 etc. But i want a regular expression like this "12.4". First two digit and decimal point and followed by a single digit.

```
ValidationExpression="^-?[0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-5]{1,1})?$|^-?(100)(\.[0]{1,2})?$"
```

Comment: Your description is unclear. Out of your sample inputs `[12, -1.0, 12.0, 12.5, 1.0]`, which ones do you want to match and which don't you want to match?

Comment: might have to be clearer with the set of excepted and excluded numbers. in your example you say that you dont want 12.5 but want 12.4??

Comment: i need the exact digit like this two digit.single digit. The final single digit is 5 only. "10.5" like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, that regex is severely overcomplicated. The whole thing could be rewritten as

```
^-?([0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-5])?|100(\.00?)?)$
```

...and have the exact same effect. But based on your comment, you're looking for something much more strict:

```
^[0-9]{2}\.5$
```

I'm not clear on why you want to do that, but this does exactly what you've described. If you don't want to force the last digit to be 5 (your comment was unclear), use `^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]$`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code on **ASPX** Page. Use `^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$` in ValidationExpression property.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtprice" width="50" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="Decimal Only" ControlToValidate="txtprice"
      ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = `@"^\d{1,2}\.\d$"`;
```

Beginning of string - two digits - decimal point - single digit. No minus, no integers. Is that what you want?

Comment: It sounded that way to me too, so have an upvote. Incidentally, [`\d` also matches unicode digits in .NET regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), which is why I went with `[0-9]` given the oddly strict requirements.

Comment: Actual that's beginning with 1 *or* 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two digits before decimal and one digit after decimal try this

```
-?[1-9][0-9][\.][0-9]
```

Comment: The `.` will match any character because you haven't escaped it. This will match `12@3`, which is wrong. Also, you don't need `-{0,1}` when `-?` works just fine.

Comment: Appears correct now, I'll remove the -1. But note that you don't need the `[]` around the `\.`, and your pattern also doesn't allow the decimal digit to be 0 (for example, it will match `12.1` but not `12.0`).

Answer (score 0):

I am tested the below expression in WPF it works fine once check this one

```
string sExpression = @"^[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]$";
```